# Looping over update query using script

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfml

Trying to figure out how to do this loop with script.

```
<cfquery>
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(myData)#" index="i">
<!--- update query with different paramaters --->
</cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

I can do it outside loop, like this, but it's slow:

```
for(i=1; i LTE arrayLen(myData); i++)
{
    q = new Query();
    q.setSql(" UPDATE SQL HERE ");
    q.addParam(name="id", value=i);
    q.Execute().GetResult();
}
```

I want to do it within the SQL, not outside of it.

UPDATE:
Here is the code.  I tried to remove some of it to make it simpler.

I have a form where the users input data and then this is called:

```
for(i=1; i LTE listlen(arguments.myStruct.myfield1); i++)   {           
    myfield1 = listgetAt(arguments.myStruct.myfield1,i);

    for(j=1; j LTE arguments.myStruct.count; j++) {
        maxvalue = form["max" & j];
        myType = form["myType" & j];
        id = myfield1;

        local.queryService = new Query();
        local.queryService.setSql
        ("          
            UPDATE  mytypes
            SET     maxvalue = :maxvalue,
                    myType = :myType
            WHERE   mytypeID = :id
        ");
        local.queryService.addParam(name="id", value=id);
        local.queryService.addParam(name="maxvalue", value=maxvalue, cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer");
        local.queryService.addParam(name="myType", value=myType, cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer");
        local.queryService.Execute().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you just asking for the syntax of cfloop in cfscript? [Using CFScript statements](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a0e0-7fdf.html#WSbfbbf049491c37b01e63e3d12a0d4447d9-8000)  Not sure how that translates over to railo.

Comment: .. or are you just having problems with your tag based version? If so, post the `sql` you have tried and any error messages. Also what is your database type and how many updates are you talking about?

Comment: I can do it this way:

for(i=1; i LTE arrayLen(myData); i++) {
 q = new Query();
 local.queryService.setSql
 ("      
  UPDATE SQL HERE
 ");
 q.addParam(name="id", value=i);
 q.Execute().GetResult();
}

But I want to do it within the SQL, not outside of it.

Comment: What about the other questions: db type and number of updates?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  Using MySQL and about 100 or so.

Comment: Are you wanting to update fields to the value of the array item based on the index? 
   
That sounds like multiple updates; you should check your indexes and investigate transactions if it's being slow.

Comment: Hm.. I cannot tell from the sample if you really need multiple updates or just an `IN (...)` clause. Is the actual sql updating each record with a *different* value or just updating a bunch of records with the same value?

Comment: I will check the index, but I think it's fine.  The updating is updating each record with a different value.

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading [Adam's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13018205/104223), I agree we need to see the original update query. I am not 100% sure what your goal is, but here is my "guess". If you want to update multiple records with different values, for example:

```
   UPDATE Table Col = 'xxx' WHERE ID = 1 ;
   UPDATE Table Col = 'yyy' WHERE ID = 2 ;
   ...
```

.. you could build the string and add the parameters within the loop. See adaptation of Adam's example below. Note, you need to enable the "Allow multiple Queries" setting in your datasource for it to work. Also, be sure to wrap the `execute()` call in a transaction to maintain data integrity.

**EDIT** Modified the previous example based on your updates:

```
<cfscript>
    // initialize these before any looping
    q = new Query();
    q.setDatasource("yourDSNHere");

    sqlArray = [];

    for(i=1; i LTE listlen(arguments.myStruct.myfield1); i++)   {           
        id = listgetAt(arguments.myStruct.myfield1,i);

        for(j=1; j LTE arguments.myStruct.count; j++) {
           // extract input values
           maxValue = form["max" & j];
           myType = form["myType" & j];

           // append a new statement
           arrayAppend(sqlArray, "UPDATE  mytypes 
                                  SET     maxvalue  = ?
                                        , myType = ? 
                                  WHERE myTypeID= ? "
                         );

           // add in the parameter values
           q.addParam(value="#maxValue#", cfSqlType="cf_sql_integer");
           q.addParam(value="#myType#", cfSqlType="cf_sql_integer");
           q.addParam(value="#id#", cfSqlType="cf_sql_integer");
    }

    // finally convert to single SQL string and run it
    q.setSQL( arrayToList(sqlArray, ";") );
    q.execute();
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear what kind of information you need to work with inside your loop, but one way to do this is to build your update statement and then output it inside your cfquery. Here is another way of doing this in cfscript though:

```
<cfscript>
myData = ArrayNew(2);

myData[1][1] = "test";

myData[1][2] = "1";

for (row = 1; row LTE ArrayLen(myData); row++) {

    queryService = new query(); 

    queryService.setSQL('UPDATE mytable SET myfield = "#myData[row][1]#" where table_id=#myData[row][2]#');

    result = queryService.execute();
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Warning, warning, sql injection danger Will Robinson ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what you're actually asking, but this might be the answer to it?

```
<cfscript>
// dunno what your data is, but you need a col and a value so let's pretend you have those
myData = [
    {col="col1", value="one"},
    {col="col2", value="two"},
    {col="col3", value="three"}
];      


q = new Query(datasource="scratch_mysql");

sql = "UPDATE tbl_test2 SET ";
for (i=1; i <= arrayLen(myData); i++){
    q.addParam(value=myData[i].value);  // you might want a type here as well?
    sql &= " #myData[i].col# = ?";
    if (i < arrayLen(myData)){  
        sql &= ",";
    }
}
sql &= " WHERE id=1";

q.setSql(sql);
q.execute();
</cfscript>
```

I'm going to vote you down until you make your question clearer.  It's the first `<cfquery>` bit that needs clarifying: what it is you're doing now.  If we knew that, we'd know how to tell you how to do it in script.

Comment: Huh, never knew CF allowed unnamed parameters ie jdbc style bind `?`

Comment: It's right there in the docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0693d5dae123bcd28f6d-7ffb.html.  It's not focused-upon, but it's there.  This is how CF has always previously passed parameters. It's the ability to name them that's new.  Look at the debug output of a parameterised `<cfquery>`: the placeholders are all `?`.

Comment: {smacks forehead} Well I am embarrassed to say I completely forgot you could use jdbc `?` syntax as of cf9 .. duh (maybe earlier in Railo). Too much time working on legacy apps as of late.